# Export multiple tables from SQL Server to XML for restore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, linq

I have a web application in C# / ASP.NET. I want to export all the database table's data, with the same unique key (`Company ID`). All the tables have this key (different for every company). I want to do that for future backup. Is it possible with Linq or classic C#? How can achieve this backup and restore?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server - you should be using the SQL Server **database backup** mechanism - not reinventing the whole thing yet again.....

Comment: @marc_s : he wants to backup selective records based on the company id for which SQL SERVER database backup is not i good idea I guess

Comment: you are able to create procedure which give you result from all tables base on filter of your Unique ID - Company ID then by the use of the XML FOR you are able to get xml.

Comment: There is so simple way around it...Run SQL Statements....Loop Through them and them create XML/CSV files within Loop. I would probably do them by using SQL Server Import/Export utility...Export from "QUERY to CSV" method.

Comment: Can you suggest me an example? Also do you believe I should create one xml or one xml for every database table? I am asking what is more helpful for the restore function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the example to the solution is

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connStr = "Data Source=MOHSINWIN8PRO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AB2EDEMO;Integrated Security=True";
        var xmlFileData = "";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        var tables = new[] {"Hospital", "Patient"};
        foreach (var table in tables)
        {

            var query = "SELECT * FROM "+ table +" WHERE (Hospital_Code = 'Hosp1')";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
            xmlFileData+=ds.GetXml();
        }
        File.WriteAllText("D://SelectiveDatabaseBackup.xml",xmlFileData);
    }
}
```

}

this will create `SelectiveDatabaseBackup.xml` which can be later used to restore the backup

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you tell me what datatype is var table because i have problem with var on my framework

Comment: table is string and tables is string array

Comment: When i try to assign string table,(inside foreach declaration) i take the error: The type or namespace name table could not be found

Comment: `string[] tables = new string[] {"Hospital", "Patient"};`
`foreach (string table in tables)`

Comment: The only problem is that all elements have the name table. is there any solution to have the name of every table?

Comment: didn't got you i guess you don't want to explicitly give the table name. if yes then use query `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ` to fill dataset and then iterate dataset to fill the array

Comment: how restore this script when i need

Answer (score -2):

```
               SaveFileDialog SD = new SaveFileDialog();
                if (SD.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new System.IO.StreamWriter(SD.FileName);
                    foreach (string str in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
                    {
                        string XMLSTR = //Heads.funtions.ConvertDatatableToXML(
                                        Heads.funtions.fire_qry_for_string(string.Format("Select * from {0} FOR XML AUTO,TYPE, ELEMENTS ,ROOT('{0}')", str)); // , str);
                        SW.Write(XMLSTR);
                        SW.WriteLine("###TABLEEND###");
                    }
                    SW.Close();
                    //_CommonClasses._Cls_Alerts.ShowAlert("Clean Up Completed...!!!", "CleanUP", MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
```

Comment: Code-only answers really could do with some explanation. Could you elaborate, please?