# Bulk insert XML data into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, restore

I am working on backup and restore selective data from SQL Server. I am using the following solution:

[export multiple tables from mssql to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802812/export-multiple-tables-from-sql-server-to-xml-for-restore)

and create a xml with the data I want. How can I create now a function to restore these data  into a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), you can load your data in datatable and then using SqlBulkCopy you can insert it in the table.

[**SqlBulkCopy**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

> Lets you efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from
>   another source.

and

> The SqlBulkCopy class can be used to write data only to SQL Server
>   tables. However, the data source is not limited to SQL Server; any
>   data source can be used, as long as the data can be loaded to a
>   DataTable instance or read with a IDataReader instance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you give me an example. The solution I am working on, doesn’t write on the xml the table name. Just start and close newdataset for every table and the records for every table named ”Table”. See the structure:<NewDataSet>
<Table>
    <userId>136</userId>
    <userdescription>New Customer</userdescription>
    <uservalue>N</uservalue>
    </Table>
  <Table>
    <userId>137</userId>
    <userdescription>New Buying Center</userdescription>
    <uservalue>NB</uservalue>
    </Table>
</NewDataSet>
<NewDataSet>...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use Integration Services and CSV files. Xml is too verbose and increase the amount of data needed.

Comment: Could you give me an example. I want to backup and restore selective data,not the entire db.